# How to test function inside of useDispatch in React

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-testing-library, redux-toolkit, ts-jest

I need to test this if condition to pass the coverage in Sonarqube, however the test passes but is not covered, which I think is not correctly tested. Could you explain how to test correctly?
The question is that I want to test this in the dispatch method and show the update state in react how can I achieve that?

**I have a stepper component with this logic:**

```
useEffect(() => {
    const initialStep = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await dispatch(getClaimsByUsername(useremail)).unwrap();

        if (
          response.data.propietarios.length > 0 &&
          response.data.propietarios.some((f) => f.toLowerCase() === propietario.toLowerCase())
        ) {
          dispatch(nextStep(STEPS_MESSAGES.INITIAL_STEP.MESSAGE_STEP_SUCCESS));
        }
```

**My test component ** :

```
 describe("stepper reducer", () => {
  const initialState = {
    data: {
      activeStep: 0,
      activeStepFailed: null,
      messagesStepper: {
        messageStep: "",
        messageStepFailedSub: "",
      },
      showTextAreaMotivo: false,
    },
    error: null,
    isLoading: false,
  };

  it("should dispatch nextStep action if condition is met", () => {
    const action = nextStep(STEPS_MESSAGES.INITIAL_STEP.MESSAGE_STEP_SUCCESS);
    const newState = reducer(initialState, action);

    expect(newState).toEqual({
      data: {
        activeStep: 1,
        activeStepFailed: null,
        messagesStepper: {
          messageStep: STEPS_MESSAGES.INITIAL_STEP.MESSAGE_STEP_SUCCESS,
          messageStepFailedSub: "",
        },
        showTextAreaMotivo: false,
      },
    });
  });
```

Comment: Your code lacks details, please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example